# Can ISO 27001 auditors audit their own work?

Tags: audit, iso27001

It may seem that the question in the title is stupid, but it is not. There is a known case of deletion of "*Auditors shall not audit their own work*" rule in 2015 version of ISO 9001 and the remaining text ("*select auditors and conduct audits to ensure objectivity and the impartiality of the audit process*") is identical to the one found in nowadays ISO 27001. This change was welcomed in 9001 as it was generally recognised that this was impossible for smaller companies to comply. In the case of 27001, has such a change also occurred and is understood in the same way as in 9001?